# How to get the value with one of tuples?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code

```
crel = {('hanso', 'unif', 'manjo', 'sandi'): ['coiu','lemin'],('yyy', 'qe', 'tgg', 'ijg'):['KOH','TYH']}

key = 'tgg'
for k, v in crel.items():
    if key in k:
        print(v)
    else:
        print('no result')
```

Output:

```
no result
['KOH', 'TYH']
```

I want to use one of tuples to get all the values in the list, but there is always "no result" comes out along with my desired result.

I know it's because I use "for" loop, but I have tried really hard to avoid this happening.

How do I use 'tgg'  to get the result like this:

```
['KOH', 'TYH']
```

Or, use 'hanso' to get the result like this:

```
['coiu','lemin']
```

Could someone please help me use one of the tuples and show the corresponding value?
When there is really not a match, show 'no result'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
crel = {('hanso', 'unif', 'manjo', 'sandi'): ['coiu', 'lemin'],
        ('yyy', 'qe', 'tgg', 'ijg'): ['KOH', 'TYH']}

key = 'tgg'
values = [crel[k] for k in crel.keys() if key in k]
if len(values) > 0:
    for val in values:
        print(val)
else:
    print("no result")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I want it shows 'no result' when the key doesn't match any.

Comment: Check now. This should do the thing.

Comment: Thank you! But now it shows keys. | Output:[('yyy', 'qe', 'tgg', 'ijg')]  | I would like get ['KOH', 'TYH'] Could you please help me one more time?

Comment: Check now. I've solved your particular task, but it would be nice if you dig a little bit down to dict functionality. That's my advice.

Comment: Thank you! it worked! Yes, I would take your advice. I just discovered I used |keys = [v for k,v in crel.items() if key in k]| also worked! Thank you again for helping me learning dict!